# View ajax requests in internet explorer?

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer

Is there a way to view the ongoing ajax requests in internet explorer like firebug in google chrome and firefox allows you to see?

For some reason my IE is getting stuck on an ajax request, it starts the request but the loading message I put in never goes away, leaving me clueless as to what happened, whether the request failed and if so, why. The same request works in FF and chrome.

Comment: Tools > F12 Developer tools or simply `F12` should have a `Network` tab (IE9), doesn't your ajax request appear there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Press `F12` if you are using IE8 or up or install firebug for IE.

or install

[Firebug Lite for IE](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite)

Answer (score 3):

If you're using IE9, you should definitely be using the Developer tools.
If you're using an earlier version of IE, try the [Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite) bookmarklet

You wont see network requests, but it does give you access to the console.log()

> javascript:(function(F,i,r,e,b,u,g,L,I,T,E){if(F.getElementById(b))return;E=F[i+'NS']&&F.documentElement.namespaceURI;E=E?Fi+'NS':Fi;Er;Er;Er;(Fe[0]||Fe[0]).appendChild(E);E=new%20Image;Er;})(document,'createElement','setAttribute','getElementsByTagName','FirebugLite','4','firebug-lite.js','releases/lite/latest/skin/xp/sprite.png','https://getfirebug.com/','#startOpened');

Just paste that string into the address bar in IE after you've loaded your page.